# Extract Text between HTML tags with sed or grep

Tags: html, bash, sed, grep

I have a Problem. I want to get two parts of this html in values with the sed or grep command. How i can extract both of them?

test.html:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="foo" class="foo">
   Some Text.
    <p id="author" class="author">
     <br>
     <a href="example.com">bar</a>
    </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

author=$(sed 's/.*<p id="author" class="author"><br><a href="*">\(.*\)<\/a><\/p>.*/\1/p' test.html)
quote=$(sed 's/.*<div id="foo" class="foo">\(.*\)<\/div>.*/\1/p' test.html)
```

Under the line i want only the text in the values. without the html tags.
But my script doesent works..

Comment: use html parsers like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlstarlet/info and not regex

Comment: What should $author and $quote contain?

Comment: I cant use the xmlstarlet. I have no sudo access.

Comment: @Cyrus author -> "bar" and quote -> "Some Text."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The code:

```
text="$(sed 's:^ *::g' < test.html | tr -d \\n)"
author=$(sed 's:.*<p id="author" class="author"><br><a href="[^"]*">\([^<]*\)<.*:\1:' <<<"$text")
quote=$(sed 's:.*<div id="foo" class="foo">\([^<]*\)<.*:\1:' <<<"$text")
echo "'$author' '$quote'"
```

#### How it works:

1. `$text` is assigned an unindented single-line representation of `test.html`; note that `:` is used as a delimiter for `sed` instead of `/`, since any character is capable of being a delimiter, and the text we are parsing has `/`-s present, so we don`t have to escape them with `\`-s when constructing a regex.
2. `$author` is assumed to be between `<p id="author" class="author"><br><a href="[^"]*">` (where `[^"]*` means «any characters except `"`, repeated N times, N ∈ [0, +∞)») and any tag that comes next.
3. `$quote` is assumed to be between `<div id="foo" class="foo">` and any tag that comes next.
4. The rather obscure construct `<<<"$text"` is the so-called [here-string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), which is almost equivalent to `echo "$text" |` placed at the beginning.

Comment: The quote part doesnt works. It returns the complete string

Comment: @meteor try it on `test.html` from your question. It does work: http://ideone.com/9pPZoZ

Answer (score 2):

You can use [html2text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/)

```
# cat test.html | html2text
Some Text.


[bar](example.com)
```

I'm using very often with curl

```
# curl -s http://www.example.com/ | html2text

# Example Domain

This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

[More information...](https://www.iana.org/domains/example)

#
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xmllint](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) to parse html/xml text and extract values for defined xpath.

Here is the working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

author=$(xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class="foo"]/text()' test.html | tr -d '\n' | sed -e "s/ //g")
quote=$(xmllint --html --xpath '//a/text()' test.html | sed -e "s/ //g")
echo "Author:'$author'"
echo "Quote:'$quote'"
```

- ***xpath*** defines xml node path from which text needs to be extracted.
- ***tr*** is used remove new-line characters.
- ***sed*** is used to trim string from extracted text value.

Comment: I know a xpath a bit from XSL, so I appreciate this solution very much.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please [don't use regex to parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858), but use a dedicated parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead:

```
$ xidel -s test.html -e '//p/a,//div/normalize-space(text())'
bar
Some Text.
```

```
$ eval $(xidel test.html -se 'author:=//p/a,quote:=//div/normalize-space(text())' --output-format=bash)

$ printf '%s\n' "$author" "$quote"
bar
Some Text.
```